# How to hide script(angular) fields that assigned on source code?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I developed .Net MVC Project ,I used AngularJS library on front side.

Here is the problem;

I'm preparing some view model to use at front side. But view model which is assigned in angular side, displaying source code. Thus, source code size is increasing day by day.

For example:
Script code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.objectList = @Html.Raw(Model);
});
```

In source code :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.objectList = [1,4,5,6,7];//bla bla
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: On this `@Html.Raw(Model)` is the Model a list?

Comment: Yes , you are right Bosco